# How to resolve ClassNotFoundException with specific Axis2 and Axiom combinations in Tomcat 9 and Java 11?

Tags: java, apache-axis, classnotfoundexception, tomcat9, axiom

Hello StackOverflow community,

I'm having difficulties with my web project running on Apache Tomcat 9.0.62, using Java 11. My application uses the Axis2 (1.7.9) and Axiom (1.4.0) libraries for the creation and manipulation of web services.

During runtime, I'm encountering two `ClassNotFoundException` errors. Here are the full errors:

1. `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.OMMetaFactoryEx`
2. `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.axis.transport.http.AdminServlet`

Full error:

```java
SEVERE: Servlet.init() para servlet [AxisServlet] lanzó excepción
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.apache.axis2.description.AxisDescription.<init>(AxisDescription.java:72)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisConfiguration.<init>(AxisConfiguration.java:175)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.populateAxisConfiguration(DeploymentEngine.java:627)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.WarBasedAxisConfigurator.<init>(WarBasedAxisConfigurator.java:157)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.initConfigContext(AxisServlet.java:620)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.init(AxisServlet.java:471)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1164)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1010)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4957)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5264)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:835)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:263)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:432)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:345)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:476)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/axiom/soap/impl/builder/OMMetaFactoryEx
    at org.apache.axiom.om.OMAbstractFactory.<clinit>(OMAbstractFactory.java:116)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/axiom/soap/impl/builder/OMMetaFactoryEx
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2489)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:875)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1376)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1220)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2489)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:875)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1376)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1220)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.dom.factory.OMDOMMetaFactoryLoader.load(OMDOMMetaFactoryLoader.java:28)
    at org.apache.axiom.locator.ImplementationFactory.parseImplementation(ImplementationFactory.java:142)
    at org.apache.axiom.locator.ImplementationFactory.parseDescriptor(ImplementationFactory.java:99)
    at org.apache.axiom.locator.DefaultOMMetaFactoryLocator.<init>(DefaultOMMetaFactoryLocator.java:87)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.OMAbstractFactory.<clinit>(OMAbstractFactory.java:106)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.OMMetaFactoryEx
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1412)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1220)
    ... 62 more

jul. 04, 2023 12:18:10 P. M. org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet [AxisServlet] in web application [/proyectWebService] threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.OMMetaFactoryEx
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1412)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1220)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2489)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:875)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1376)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1220)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2489)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:875)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1376)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1220)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.dom.factory.OMDOMMetaFactoryLoader.load(OMDOMMetaFactoryLoader.java:28)
    at org.apache.axiom.locator.ImplementationFactory.parseImplementation(ImplementationFactory.java:142)
    at org.apache.axiom.locator.ImplementationFactory.parseDescriptor(ImplementationFactory.java:99)
    at org.apache.axiom.locator.DefaultOMMetaFactoryLocator.<init>(DefaultOMMetaFactoryLocator.java:87)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.OMAbstractFactory.<clinit>(OMAbstractFactory.java:106)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.AxisDescription.<init>(AxisDescription.java:72)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisConfiguration.<init>(AxisConfiguration.java:175)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.populateAxisConfiguration(DeploymentEngine.java:627)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.WarBasedAxisConfigurator.<init>(WarBasedAxisConfigurator.java:157)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.initConfigContext(AxisServlet.java:620)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.init(AxisServlet.java:471)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1164)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1010)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4957)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5264)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:835)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:263)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:432)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:345)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:476)

jul. 04, 2023 12:18:10 P. M. org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
```

I've experimented with various combinations of the Axis and Axiom libraries, from Axis 1.6 to Axiom 1.3. Based on my project requirements and compatibility, Axis 1.7.9 and Axiom 1.4.0 work best for me. Despite these efforts, and also attempting to add the JAR files manually both to the project and to the Tomcat server, the errors persist.

Here are the additional details of my setup:

- JDK: 11
- Server: Apache Tomcat 9.0.62
- Libraries:

  - Axis2: 1.7.9
  - Axiom: 1.4.0

My pom.xml

```xml
<properties>
    <axiom.version>1.4.0</axiom.version>
    <axis2.version>1.7.9</axis2.version>
</properties>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
    <artifactId>axis2-kernel</artifactId>
    <version>${axis2.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
    <artifactId>axis2</artifactId>
    <version>${axis2.version}</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
    <artifactId>axis2-transport-base</artifactId>
    <version>${axis2.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
    <artifactId>axis2-transport-local</artifactId>
    <version>${axis2.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
    <artifactId>axis2-transport-http</artifactId>
    <version>${axis2.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
    <artifactId>axis2-adb</artifactId>
    <version>${axis2.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.axiom</groupId>
    <artifactId>axiom-api</artifactId>
    <version>${axiom.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.axiom</groupId>
    <artifactId>axiom-impl</artifactId>
    <version>${axiom.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.axiom</groupId>
    <artifactId>axiom-jaxb</artifactId>
    <version>${axiom.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.axiom</groupId>
    <artifactId>axiom-dom</artifactId>
    <version>${axiom.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

**Dependency tree**

```
[INFO] --------------------< es.organization:proyect-ws >---------------------
[INFO] Building proyect-ws 1.0.0
[INFO] --------------------------------[ war ]---------------------------------
[WARNING] The artifact javax.xml:jaxrpc:jar:1.1 has been relocated to javax.xml:jaxrpc-api:jar:1.1
[WARNING] The artifact org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:2.0.0 has been relocated to org.slf4j:slf4j-reload4j:jar:2.0.0
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ proyect-ws ---
[WARNING] The artifact javax.xml:jaxrpc:jar:1.1 has been relocated to javax.xml:jaxrpc-api:jar:1.1
[WARNING] The artifact org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:2.0.0 has been relocated to org.slf4j:slf4j-reload4j:jar:2.0.0
[INFO] es.organization:proyect-ws:war:1.0.0
[INFO] +- org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-dom:jar:1.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-api:jar:1.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- jaxen:jaxen:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.james:apache-mime4j-core:jar:0.8.6:compile
[INFO] |  \- jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:jar:1.2.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-jaxb:jar:1.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:jar:2.3.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.axis2:axis2:pom:1.7.9:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.axis2:axis2-adb:jar:1.7.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.axis2:axis2-kernel:jar:1.7.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-ws-metadata_2.0_spec:jar:1.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jta_1.1_spec:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.woden:woden-core:jar:1.0M10:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- javax.ws.rs:jsr311-api:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-activation_1.1_spec:jar:1.0.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.axis2:axis2-adb-codegen:jar:1.7.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.ws.xmlschema:xmlschema-core:jar:2.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.axis2:axis2-clustering:jar:1.7.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomcat:tribes:jar:6.0.53:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.tomcat:juli:jar:6.0.53:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.axis2:axis2-codegen:jar:1.7.9:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-tools:jar:2.2.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.axis2:axis2-corba:jar:1.7.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.axis2:axis2-metadata:jar:1.7.9:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.axis2:axis2-fastinfoset:jar:1.7.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.sun.xml.fastinfoset:FastInfoset:jar:1.2.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:jar:1.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.neethi:neethi:jar:3.0.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.axis2:axis2-java2wsdl:jar:1.7.9:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.axis2:axis2-jaxbri:jar:1.7.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.2.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-xjc:jar:2.2.6:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.2.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.axis2:axis2-jaxws:jar:1.7.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-annotation_1.0_spec:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jaxws_2.2_spec:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- xml-resolver:xml-resolver:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- xalan:xalan:jar:2.7.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.axis2:axis2-ant-plugin:jar:1.7.9:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.ant:ant:jar:1.7.0:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.apache.ant:ant-launcher:jar:1.7.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.axis2:axis2-json:jar:1.7.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.jettison:jettison:jar:1.3.8:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.axis2:axis2-saaj:jar:1.7.9:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-saaj_1.3_spec:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] +- xom:xom:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.6.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.ibm.icu:icu4j:jar:2.6.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.ws.commons.schema:XmlSchema:jar:1.4.7:compile
[INFO] +- xerces:xmlParserAPIs:jar:2.6.0:compile
[INFO] +- wsdl4j:wsdl4j:jar:1.6.2:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.woodstox:woodstox-core:jar:6.2.8:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:jar:4.2.1:compile
[INFO] +- jdom:jdom:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] +- javax.xml:jaxrpc-api:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.glassfish:javax.faces:jar:2.1.6:compile
[INFO] +- javax.el:javax.el-api:jar:2.2.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.axis2:axis2-xmlbeans:jar:1.7.9:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:jar:2.6.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.axis2:axis2-transport-local:jar:1.7.9:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.axis2:axis2-mtompolicy:jar:1.7.9:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.axis2:axis2-transport-http:jar:1.7.9:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.3:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.6:compile
[INFO] +- javax.xml.soap:javax.xml.soap-api:jar:1.4.0:compile
[INFO] +- ca.uhn.hapi:hapi-base:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO] +- ca.uhn.hapi:hapi-structures-v25:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO] +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:2.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:5.6.3.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.4.2.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.1.2.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.persistence:javax.persistence-api:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.11.20:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec:jar:1.1.1.Final:compile
[INFO] +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.15:compile
[INFO] +- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk16:jar:1.46:compile
[INFO] +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.11.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.icefaces:icefaces-compat:jar:3.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.icefaces:icefaces:jar:3.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.servlet:jstl:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.32:compile
[INFO] +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.5:compile
[INFO] |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.5:compile
[INFO] +- es.organization:proyect-neg:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- es.organization:proyect-per:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.media.jai:com.springsource.javax.media.jai.core:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.media.jai:com.springsource.javax.media.jai.codec:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.github.jai-imageio:jai-imageio-core:jar:1.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-impl:jar:1.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- backport-util-concurrent:backport-util-concurrent:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.woden:woden-api:jar:1.0M9:compile
[INFO] |  +- ca.uhn.hapi:hapi-structures-v231:jar:2.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.dom4j:dom4j:jar:2.1.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.icefaces:icefaces-ace:jar:3.3.0:compile
[INFO] +- javax.annotation:jsr250-api:jar:1.0:provided
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:jsp-api:jar:2.0:provided
[INFO] +- javax.faces:jsf-impl:jar:1.2_13:provided
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5:provided
[INFO] +- org.icepush:icepush:jar:3.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.servlet.jsp:jsp-api:jar:2.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.mail:mail:jar:1.4.1:compile
[INFO] |     \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:5.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- com.microsoft.sqlserver:sqljdbc4:jar:4.0:compile
[INFO] +- cglib:cglib:jar:2.1_3:compile
[INFO] |  \- asm:asm:jar:1.5.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:5.0.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:5.0.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:5.0.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- com.sun.faces:jsf-impl:jar:2.1.7:compile
[INFO] +- com.sun.faces:jsf-api:jar:2.1.7:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:5.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:5.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:5.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.6.3.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss:jandex:jar:2.2.3.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.5.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.activation:javax.activation-api:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:jar:2.3.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.glassfish.jaxb:txw2:jar:2.3.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.sun.istack:istack-commons-runtime:jar:3.0.7:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.jvnet.staxex:stax-ex:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.2.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:7.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.oracle.database.jdbc:ojdbc10:jar:19.16.0.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-reload4j:jar:2.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- ch.qos.reload4j:reload4j:jar:1.2.19:compile
[INFO] +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO] +- com.itextpdf:itextpdf:jar:5.5.0:compile
[INFO] +- commons-discovery:commons-discovery:jar:0.5:compile
[INFO] +- org.glassfish.web:el-impl:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.el:el-api:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] \- net.sourceforge.jtds:jtds:jar:1.2.8:compile
```

Has anyone faced this issue before or have any idea on how to solve these `ClassNotFoundException` errors? Any suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that Axis2 and Axiom jars are included in your application's WEB-INF/lib directory?

Comment: Yes, I am certain. I have tried adding the libraries both with Maven and manually. In addition, I have included them in both the WEB-INF/lib folder of the project and on the server. Despite these attempts, the errors persist. I would appreciate any other suggestions.

Comment: Can you exec `mvn dependency:tree` to check transitive dependencies? Maybe there is some conflicts

Comment: I've already run the command to view the dependency tree and have posted it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was finally able to solve my problem, which was being affected by three key factors.

1. **Axis2 and Axiom Versions:** I had to revert back to older versions of axis2 and axiom to avoid conflicts. The versions that finally worked for me are as follows:

   ```xml
   <axiom.version>1.2.13</axiom.version>
   <axis2.version>1.6.2</axis2.version>
   ```
2. **Library Load Order:** The order in which libraries were loading in my project was also affecting things. Be sure to check and adjust this as needed in your own project.
3. **JDK 11 Incompatibilities:** I also ran into an issue where `javax.xml.stream` was accessible by more than one module. To fix this, I had to exclude the following libraries from my dependencies:

   ```xml
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.axiom</groupId>
       <artifactId>axiom-api</artifactId>
       <version>${axiom.version}</version>
       <exclusions>
           <exclusion>
               <groupId>org.apache.james</groupId>
               <artifactId>apache-mime4j-core</artifactId>
           </exclusion>
           <exclusion>
               <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
               <artifactId>
                   geronimo-activation_1.1_spec
               </artifactId>
           </exclusion>
           <exclusion>
               <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
               <artifactId>geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec</artifactId>
           </exclusion>
       </exclusions>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.axiom</groupId>
       <artifactId>axiom-impl</artifactId>
       <version>${axiom.version}</version>
       <exclusions>
           <exclusion>
               <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
               <artifactId>
                   geronimo-activation_1.1_spec
               </artifactId>
           </exclusion>
           <exclusion>
               <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
               <artifactId>geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec</artifactId>
           </exclusion>
       </exclusions>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.axiom</groupId>
       <artifactId>axiom-dom</artifactId>
       <version>${axiom.version}</version>
       <exclusions>
           <exclusion>
               <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
               <artifactId>
                   geronimo-activation_1.1_spec
               </artifactId>
           </exclusion>
       </exclusions>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
       <artifactId>axis2-adb</artifactId>
       <version>${axis2.version}</version>
       <exclusions>
           <exclusion>
               <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
               <artifactId>
                   geronimo-activation_1.1_spec
               </artifactId>
           </exclusion>
       </exclusions>
   </dependency>
   ```

I hope this information can help someone else facing similar issues. Thanks to everyone for the help provided.

Answer (score 0):

`org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.OMMetaFactoryEx` is a class that only existed in Axiom 1.2.x. The only explanation for that exception I can think of is that the code ends up trying to load a version of the `org.apache.axiom.om.impl.dom.factory.OMDOMMetaFactoryLoader` class from Axiom 1.2.x. One reason would be that there is an old `axiom-dom` JAR somewhere in the classpath.

Comment: Thank you for your information. I too suspect that this may be the cause of the error, but I can't seem to pinpoint the exact problem. Axis2 1.7.9 does rely on Axiom versions lower than 1.3.0, however, Eclipse indicates that these are skipped due to the use of version 1.4.0. As far as I know, Axis2 1.7.9 is compatible with Axiom 1.4.0.