How to create a JAVA SOAP Web Service?
I want to create a SOAP Web Service. I am using JDK 17, Axis2 1.8.2, Tomcat 10.1, Eclips (2024-03).
I want to implement some endpoints to call with SOAP UI or other client.
Issues:
After creating the web service and run on server (tomcat 10.1) gives me HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error.
Full error:
HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error
Type Exception Report
Message Error instantiating servlet class [org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet]
Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.
Exception
jakarta.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class [org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet]
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:663)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:389)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1741)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1190)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63)
java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Root Cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1332)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1144)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:663)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:389)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1741)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1190)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63)
java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.
Apache Tomcat/10.1.24
Code:
Class:
package com.abc.web;

public class MyWSImpl implements MyWS {

    @Override
    public int getNum() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 20;
    }

}

Interface:
package com.abc.web;

public interface MyWS {
public int getNum();
}

Web.xml:
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>My Web Service</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>/axis2-web/index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <display-name>Apache-Axis Servlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>AxisServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AxisServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/servlet/AxisServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AxisServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jws</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AxisServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <display-name>Apache-Axis Admin Servlet Web Admin</display-name>
    <servlet-name>AxisAdminServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisAdminServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>100</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AxisAdminServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/axis2-admin/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>`

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!
Tried:

Creting endpoints or call back methods.

Expected:

Can call those endpoint via API tools(Postman, SOAP UI).

Resulted:

HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error.


Do you have axis2-transport-http dependency in your war / app server?

@WladimirDiskowski Yes. in eclips-workspace\My Web Service\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\lib. axis2-transport-http-1.8.2.jar including org.apache.axis2.transport.http package. Thanks, for the responce.

Probably something along the lines of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76611834/how-to-resolve-classnotfoundexception-with-specific-axis2-and-axiom-combinations

Axis2 libraries not compatible with Tomcat 10 (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AXIS2-6035)

@life888888, thank you for your response and assistance. Should I opt for Tomcat 9 in this scenario? Additionally, which should I use: Jakarta or Javax?
Could you also provide any suggestions on the configuration to use?

@MD HABIBULLA  "https://github.com/shyangs/blog/issues/30" , Tomcat 9 , Axis 2 , JDK 1.8

Please note that this article mentions that the POJO class to be used as a Service cannot have a Package name. "https://www.weichen.idv.tw/wordpress/2021/04/20/axis2-tomcat-%E4%BD%BF%E7%94%A8%E7%B4%80%E9%8C%84/"

@life888888, thank you. I will create a custom web service.
Does JDK 1.8 mean Java 8? I have downloaded JavaSetup8u411, but in C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202, it says 1.8.
Thank you again for your help.

@MD HABIBULLA  (1) JDK 1.8 = JDK 8  (2)  JAVA SOAP Web Service also has other options, you can also choose to use JAX-WS (Java API for XML Web Services), which can support the new version of JDK and Tomcat 10.1.

Thank you, everyone. Your assistance is appreciated. @life888888, I will attempt to create it using JAX-WS.

Using JAX-WS, I was finally able to create a web service and its endpoints. However, using Axis is still problematic for me.
Happy Coding :)
